# BellmanFord con nodo Intermedio

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente algoritmo de BellmanFord mediante programación dinámica que lo que hace en pocas palabras es hallar el camino más corto entre dos vértices de un grafo, cada arista del grafo tiene un peso dado. En este caso dado, como quiero hayar la distancia más corta entre dos ciudades, hago uso de TreeMap y TreeSet.

Lo que quiero conseguir a partir de este código, es encontrar la mínima distancia que hay entre dos ciudades pasando por un nodo intermedio, por ejemplo, la distancia más corta de Almería Granada es de 173km, pero si quiero pasar por Murcia, el camino más corto sería Almería-Granada-Murcia y 502km.

Este es el código proporcionado.

```
public class BellmanFord {

        public static class Arista implements Comparable<Arista>{
            String fuente, dest;
            int peso;
    
            public Arista(String fuente, String dest, int peso) {
                this.fuente = fuente;
                this.dest = dest;
                this.peso = peso;
            }
    
            public int compareTo(Arista otraArista) {
                if (this.peso < otraArista.peso) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (this.peso == otraArista.peso) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
        public static class Vertex {
            String id;
            int peso;
            Vertex previo; 
            
            public Vertex(String id, int peso) {
                this.id = id;
                this.peso = peso;
                this.previo = null;
            }
        }
            
        
        public static int bellmanFord(TreeMap<String, Vertex> vertices, TreeSet<Arista> aristas, String fuente, String destino) {
            
            TreeMap<String, Integer> distancia = new TreeMap<>();
            TreeMap<String, Vertex> predecesor = new TreeMap<>();
    
            for (String v : vertices.keySet()) {
                if (v.equals(fuente)) {
                    distancia.put(v, 0);
                } else {
                    distancia.put(v, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                }
                predecesor.put(v, null);
            }
    
            distancia.put(fuente, 0);
    
            for (int i = 1; i < vertices.size(); i++) {
                for (Arista a : aristas) {
                    String u = a.fuente;
                    String v = a.dest;
                    int w = a.peso;
    
                    if (distancia.get(u) != Integer.MAX_VALUE && distancia.get(u) + w < distancia.get(v)) {
                        distancia.put(v, distancia.get(u) + w);
                        predecesor.put(v, vertices.get(u));
                    }
                }
            }
    
            for (Arista a : aristas) {
                String u = a.fuente;
                String v = a.dest;
                int w = a.peso;
    
                if (distancia.get(u) != Integer.MAX_VALUE && distancia.get(u) + w < distancia.get(v)) {
                    System.out.println("El grafo contiene un ciclo negativo.");
                    return -1;
                }
            }
            
            return distancia.get(destino);
         }
}
```

Los pasos que se sigue para hacer BellmanFord con PD es:

- Inicializar todos los vertices a infinito menos el inicial.
- Establecer la distancia del vertice de inicio a 0.
- Iterar sobre las aristas V-1 veces
- Buscar si hay ciclos negativos
- Devuelve la distancia mínima final.

El test que trato de ejecutar es este con el siguiente grafo:

```
@Test
    public void testBellmanFord2() {
         
        // Creamos los vertices
        TreeMap<String, BellmanFord2.Vertex> vertices = new TreeMap<>();
        vertices.put("Almeria", new Vertex("Almeria", 0));
        vertices.put("Granada", new Vertex("Granada", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Cadiz", new Vertex("Cadiz", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Huelva", new Vertex("Huelva", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Sevilla", new Vertex("Sevilla", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Jaen", new Vertex("Jaen", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Murcia", new Vertex("Murcia", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Caceres", new Vertex("Caceres", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Badajoz", new Vertex("Badajoz", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Albacete", new Vertex("Albacete", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Valencia", new Vertex("Valencia", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Madrid", new Vertex("Madrid", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Barcelona", new Vertex("Barcelona", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Gerona", new Vertex("Gerona", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Lerida", new Vertex("Lerida", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Zaragoza", new Vertex("Zaragoza", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Bilbao", new Vertex("Bilbao", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Oviedo", new Vertex("Oviedo", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Valladolid", new Vertex("Valladolid", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Vigo", new Vertex("Vigo", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        vertices.put("Corunya", new Vertex("Corunya", Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        
        // Creamos las aristas
        TreeSet<BellmanFord2.Arista> aristas = new TreeSet<>();
        aristas.add(new Arista("Almeria", "Granada", 173));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Almeria", "Murcia", 224));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Granada", "Murcia", 278));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Granada", "Jaen", 99));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Granada", "Sevilla", 256));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Cadiz", "Sevilla", 125));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Huelva", "Sevilla", 92));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Huelva", "Badajoz", 234));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Sevilla", "Jaen", 242));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Jaen", "Madrid", 335));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Murcia", "Albacete", 150));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Murcia", "Valencia", 241));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Caceres", "Badajoz", 90));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Badajoz", "Madrid", 403));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Albacete", "Valencia", 191));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Albacete", "Madrid", 251));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Valencia", "Barcelona", 349));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Madrid", "Zaragoza", 325));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Madrid", "Bilbao", 395));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Madrid", "Valladolid", 193));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Barcelona", "Zaragoza", 296));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Barcelona", "Gerona", 100));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Gerona", "Lerida", 222));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Zaragoza", "Bilbao", 324));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Bilbao", "Valladolid", 280));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Bilbao", "Oviedo", 304));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Valladolid", "Vigo", 356));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Valladolid", "Corunya", 455));
        aristas.add(new Arista("Vigo", "Corunya", 171));
        
        int distancia = BellmanFord2.bellmanFord(vertices, aristas, "Almeria", "Corunya", "Madrid");
        int distancia2 = BellmanFord2.bellmanFord(vertices, aristas, "Almeria", "Zaragoza", "Sevilla");
        
        assertEquals(1255, distancia);
        assertEquals(1331, distancia2);
    }
```

El metodo bellmanFord recibe por parámetros un TreeMap<String, Vertex> vertices, TreeSet aristas, String fuente, String destino, String nodoIntermedio.
El 1255 es la distancia más corta que hay entre Almeria y Corunya pasando por Madrid y 1331 es la distancia mas corta que hay yendo desde Almeria a Zaragoza pasando por Sevilla.

Comment: Y cual es el problema?

Comment: este algoritmo lo que hace es encontrar el camino mas corto entre dos ciudades, pero no pasa por ningun nodo intermedio

Comment: ok.. entonces lo tuyo no es una pregunta, si no un pedido para que alguien modifique todo ese codigo para que pase por un node intermedio?? intentaste algo?

Comment: si, he estado esta mañana 6 horas para intentar algo, publico esto para ver si hay alguien que se le ocurre alguna manera de hacerlo ya que yo no lo he conseguido. Gracias

Comment: Agrega lo que intentaste, asi podemos ayudarte a resolverlo mejor... si no parece un "haganme el ejercicio"